# Run multiple SQL scripts through batch file from C#

Tags: c#

I am writing code that executes SQL scripts from different folders through a batch file. There are many folders on the `U` drive, and in each folder, there are 23 SQL scripts. I have to execute all of these scripts from all folders.

Folders can be more or less, but there are always 23 scripts in each folder. I am getting an error

> The syntax of the command is incorrect

The code below has two parts first to create batch files, second to execute the SQL scripts thorough those created batch files. Please help me - where am I wrong in executing scripts i.e 2nd part of code?

Creating the batch files:

```
string file = @"U:\TDScripts";
string y = File.ReadAllText(@"U:\scriptexe.txt");

foreach (string name in Directory.GetDirectories(file))
{
    var letter = string.Join("_", name.Split('_').Take(2));
    var x = letter.ToUpper();

    Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name));

    string s = name;

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(name + ".bat"));
    sw.WriteLine(y.Replace("Filename", x)
                  .Replace("File", letter)
                  .Replace("/path", file)
                  .Replace("{folder}", s)
                  .Replace(@"U:\TDScripts\", "")
                  .Replace(@"U:\TDSCRIPTS\", "_") 
                  .Replace("/", @"\")
                  .Replace("{", "")
                  .Replace("}", "") 
                  .Replace(@"\path", file));
    sw.Close();
```

Executing the SQL scripts:

```
int exitCode;

ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
Process process;

processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c" + s);
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.WorkingDirectory = s;

process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit();

exitCode = process.ExitCode;

Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: " + exitCode.ToString(), "ExecuteCommand" + "\r\n\r\n\r\n");
process.Close();

if (!exitCode.Equals(0))
{
    break;
}
```

Comment: `"/c" + s` is there a space missing? `"/c " +s` ?

Comment: Id suggest checking the content of your batch file - why not just run the sql direct (out of interest)

Comment: What a bizarre way to do a batch of sql... Why do you not read the sql files in and use SqlCommand to run them??

Comment: @Milney i have multiple requirements and this is the last step of all requirement .i can explain if  its not annoying to you

Comment: @BugFinder how can i run the scripts from multiple folders through a single batch file?any suugestions

Comment: @AdnanHaider - I can't think of a single reason you would create a bat script then run it from C#, anything you do in your bat file can be done in C# in a more readable and robust way. I would seriously reconsider your design

Comment: @AdnanHaider the main reason we are considering this as poor design is from this you have no idea how well any of those batch files ran. if any of the sql failed, etc where as by using c# marginally different you could log and handle errors

Comment: @Milney these batch files are used in BTEQ thats why i have to create them

Comment: @AdnanHaider What do you mean they are used in BTEQ? BTEQ cannot run Windows BAT files... It looks like you are running them from C#...... Anyway, you can certainly connect to Teradata from C# too, no need to use bat files at all

Comment: @Milney help me regarding this in C#

Comment: @AdnanHaider - Have you tried using google? I don't know what you are trying to accomplish so can't write all the code for you... but a quick google suggests it will be simple: https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/15.11/help/DevelopingNetDataProviderforTeradataApplications.html